# How to send FIXML message with python to broker?

Tags: python, xml, api, broker

I am making a python app that will send a message via API to the broker app.
I have in documentation information that the message should be in XML format:

```
<FIXML v="5.0" r="20080317" s="20080314">
<UserReq UserReqID="0" UserReqTyp="1" Username="1234" Password="1234"/>
</FIXML>
```

1. Could you tell me how to send it in python language?
2. How to connect to that API, I have information that says:

```
In order to connect to the API, use the following registers:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/COMARCH S.A./NOL3/7/Settings:
• nca_pasync – port value for an asynchronous channel (default value: 24445),
• nca_psync – port value for a synchronous channel (default value: 24444),
• ncaset_pasync – flag informing whether the value in nca_pasync is active (1 - active, 0 -
inactive),
• ncaset_psync - a flag indicating whether the value in nca_psync is active (1 - active, 0 - inactive).
```

Comment: Usually that depends on the message broker, because different message brokers have different APIs: [stop.py](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py) for ActiveMQ, Artemis or RabbitMQ, [pika](https://github.com/pika/pika/) for Rabbit MQ, [mqlight](https://github.com/mqlight/python-mqlight) for IBM MQ etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Generaly you need to do everything manualy unfortunetly.

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 24444        # nca_psync – port value for a synchronous channel (default value: 24444) you need to check your registery for correct value.

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    message = '<FIXML v="5.0" r="20080317" s="20080314"><UserReq UserReqID="0" UserReqTyp="1" Username="YOUR_LOGIN" Password="YOUR_PASS"/></FIXML>'
    try:        
        # Send data
        enc = message.encode()
        sock.send(bytes([len(enc)]))
        sock.send(message.encode())


    finally:
        sock.close()
```

Using this code I was able to login. Please remeber you have to login to your broker first and lunch nol3 application.